# Not able to remove self created account from android using removeAccount() function of 'AccountManager' class

Tags: android, accountmanager

I have created a Account in android using 'AccountManager' class

```
        deviceAccount = new Account(EASConstants.ACCOUNT_NAME,   EASConstants.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(Context);
        am.addAccountExplicitly(deviceAccount, null, null);
```

but when I am trying to delete account using

```
        AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(Context);
        am.removeAccount(deviceAccount , null, null)
```

account is not getting removed

Please help , what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19187340/3094082. Basically, the Authenticator needs to know (through a Boolean) that removal of the account is allowed.