# Not able to remove my own custom-account

Tags: android, accountmanager

I have googled for this problem, but I did not find any solution.

I have created my own Custom-Account. When I'm trying to remove the account programmatically using the following code, the account is not be removed:

```
Account systemAccount = new Account(mainAccount.getDisplayName(), 
                                    getResources().getString(R.string.account_type));
AccountManager.get(Accounts.this).removeAccount(systemAccount, null, null);
```

Even, when I try to remove the account from Setting, nothing happened.
the account is removed only when I uninstall the application.

What should I do?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your logcat?

Comment: I had the same problem, and the account got in such a state that account could be deleted from settings only after clearing application data. My problem was that i was using Volley syncronous request for refreshing auth token, and that request blocked somehow my implementation of the AbstractAccountAuthenticator. The AccountManagerFuture in my case was never called.

Comment: Could you resolve this finally? Stuck at the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

You are not using the `Future` passed as a parameter to the `AccountManagerCallback<Boolean>#run` method.

You should provide the callback as the second parameter to: [`public AccountManagerFuture<Boolean> removeAccount (Account account, AccountManagerCallback<Boolean> callback, Handler handler)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#removeAccount%28android.accounts.Account,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Cjava.lang.Boolean%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29)

```
myAccountManager.removeAccount(myAccount, new AccountManagerCallback<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Boolean> future) {
        // This is the line that actually starts the call to remove the account.
        boolean wasAccountDeleted = future.getResult();
    }
}, null);
```

You should be careful how you call `future.getResult()`. It should not be called on the main UI thread. This example does not provide that mechanism for brevity.

Comment: `future.getResult` must handle `AuthenticatorException` and `OperationCanceledException` !

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. Always get account objects from the `AccountManager` to change them.

   ```
   final AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
   accountManager.getAccountsByType(Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE)[0];
   ```
2. Make sure if you're overriding `getAccountRemovalAllowed`on your `Authenticator`, you're returning the Bundle with a boolean value of true, this is the default behaviour.

   ```
   public Bundle getAccountRemovalAllowed(
           AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account)
           throws NetworkErrorException {
       final Bundle result = new Bundle();

       result.putBoolean(AccountManager.KEY_BOOLEAN_RESULT, true);

       return result;
   }
   ```

Comment: yes, i did explain that it's the default behaviour. I just warned if he was overriding the method.